# node.js, mongodb, countDocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count

I want to get the number of documents in the collection(MongoDB) and then use this variable in another function. But I don't understand why I can't record the result in var above-mentioned?

```
var countD;
db.db("mongouploads").collection("blocks").countDocuments({}, {}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    countD = result
});
```

And then `countD` equal undefined. Where is my fault?

Comment: Use `count` instead of `countDocuments `. like `db.getCollection('Model').count({})`