# MongoDB countDocuments() is returning an object, not a number

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm starting to learn about mongoose/MongoDB aggregation functions, and am having some basic difficulties. For example, I'm trying to do the following:

```
var myModels= require('./models/myModel');
var myCount = myModels.countDocuments({userID: "A"});
console.log(myCount );
```

I just want to count the number of documents with userID of "A" but when this prints to the console, it's printing as a whole object, instead of just a numerical count. I've read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059064/node-js-mongodb-countdocuments) but I'm still not able to solve this problem (also, is there a way, unlike in that question, to return the count directly rather than having to predefine a variable and set it in a callback function?)

I'm trying to follow the guide [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) and don't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Follow the pattern given in the question you cite.   Like most stuff in Node this is an /asynchronous/ call, so the value you want possibly doesn't even exist when the function returns.  If you don't pass a callback, you get a promise; use `.then` and `.catch` on the object you get back, etc.

Comment: As @BadZen says, take a look https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the return value of `countDocuments` is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and not a number.

You either need to wait for that Promise or use callback syntax like so:

```
var myModels= require('./models/myModel');
// this required the code to be inside an async function
var myCount = await myModels.countDocuments({userID: "A"}); 
console.log(myCount);
```

Or:

```
var myModels= require('./models/myModel');
myModels.countDocuments({userID: "A"})
     .then((myCount) =>{console.log(myCount);});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this. For the second example, I'm getting an error that await is not valid - that should still include "await" right?

Comment: Nope, the await resolves the promise, which is the same action `.then()` does.